# Extract measure alias assigned in a visual

Tags: powerbi, daxstudio, dmv

Is there an external tool for Power BI which allows automatically to extract column or measure alias name which as been assigned in a visual. Is it stored anywhere in DMV?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is in the DMV but you can see it easily enough. If you change your  .pbix to a .zip and open the archive and then extract Layout, you can open up the layout json. In there, under visual containers, config, there is an attribute for display name and the measure that is used to drive it.

[image]

Comment: By any chance, do you have at hand the Powerquery to extract both original and display name?

Comment: I can see `:[{\"displayName\":` in config part and in dataTransforms. It is the one in config, isn't it?

Comment: I don't have anything at hand but it should be straightforward to parse it in PQ. I would use the one in config, yes. I know it appears in a few places but that seems the most logical to parse out. I would create a sample .pbix with a few reports, visuals and aliased measures and get PQ working on that to make sure everything is picked up.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the column aliases (captions) from the published power bi report in a workspace?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.