# Get lineage id of a measure from thin pbix file

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery, dmv

Is there a way in PowerQuery to extract measure lineage id from a thin pbix report connected to dataset through live connection mode? I access the contents of thin pbix by unzipping it and reading the section Report/Layout.

Lineage id can be found in the DMV of dataset in a column `LineageTag`

```
select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_MEASURES
```

I want to find its counterpart in the thin report. The only way I can match a measure from dataset with its thin Report/Layout counterpart is by measure name.

Edit. The purpose of my question. Suppose we want to create a table with a [display name of a measure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74730338/1903793) (comes from thin report) and a DAX expression of the same measure (comes from dataset).

Comment: I don't think the lineage exists in the thin report. What you see in Report/Layout is what you get.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I do not want to narrow the focus to Report/Layout. Broadly, I want to join the measures of thin report with measures of dataset report.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What are the relevant inputs and outputs you need? This? `dataset pbix and thin report pbix --> measures in dataset + measures in thin report`